# React-Native : onPanResponderGrant Vs onPanResponderStart

Tags: react-native

`PanResponder.create()` has many callbacks and two of them are `onPanResponderGrant` and `onPanResponderStart`. Both callbacks getting triggered as soon as screen is touched.`react-native` official documentation doesn't have much information about these callbacks.

Can anybody let me know the difference between these two callbacks and when to use which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onPanResponderGrant` is called when a gesture is "started" while `onPanResponderStart` is called on additional gesture events.

For example, if you were to place one finger on the screen, `onPanResponderGrant` would fire, then, if a second finger is placed without removing the first `onPanResponderStart` would fire.

You can view some logic regarding this in the RN repo:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Interaction/PanResponder.js

Comment: I only came across this question because I was wondering the same. I do agree the docs should mention this and will consider opening a PR for this.